# UI not updating sounds played first in foreach loop C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, audio

I have made a card game that gets and shows player cards from resources in a UI using a foreach loop which works fine. I have recently added a card sound as well so that a sound would be played before each image is shown in the UI. However, the sounds are always played first and then the images are shown. A bit annoying...

I use sound player and playsync(). How do I force the GUI to update? (between the sounds)

Here is some of the code...

Starts with

```
//loop
foreach (var player in playerGUIs)....
//Call the sound Card_Sound(); //See below

//Update image player.img1.Source = new BitmapImage(new
Uri(("/Utilities;Component/Resources/" + card_file + ".png"),
UriKind.Relative));


private void Card_Sound()
    { //Play sound System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800); // First sleep 800 milliseconds

using (FileStream stream = File.Open(@"Resources\dealingcard.wav",
FileMode.Open)) {
    SoundPlayer myNewSound = new SoundPlayer(stream);
           myNewSound.Load();
           myNewSound.PlaySync(); }

}
```

Comment: Had trouble posting code....ugh why does this seem so difficult....Hope it is readable...

Answer (score 0):

PlaySync() will block the UI (if running on the UI thread) did you try Play()?

Comment: Tried play same result

Comment: Can you share your code? So we can take a better look?

Comment: Code foreach (var player in playerGUIs)

Comment: Did you try using Dispatcher.InvokeAsync

Comment: I tried using a dispatcher fix using this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/878ea631-c76e-49e8-9e25-81e76a3c4fe3/refresh-the-gui-in-a-wpf-application?forum=wpf

Comment: Did you dispatch the whole foreach in the dispatcher or each play individually?

Comment: I added the code from above url and then called refresh (plyer.img1.refresh()) which worked for the first card but not for the rest. In other words it showed the first card played all sounds and then showed the rest.....which was slightly better

Comment: i meant for you to try something like: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>{
foreach (var player in playerGUIs)....
});